# getting Error in JMETER in the yellow icon

Tags: jmeter

i am getting error in JMETER and i can't continue working with it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FE3e.png)

```
2024-01-09 13:59:40,121 INFO o.a.j.r.ClassFinder: Will scan jar C:\temp\Performance Testing\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\lib\ext\jmeter-plugins-perfmon-2.1.jar with filter ExtendsClassFilter [parents=[interface org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.ResultRenderer], inner=false, contains=null, notContains=null]. Consider exposing JMeter plugins via META-INF/services, and add JMeter-Skip-Class-Scanning=true manifest attribute so JMeter can skip classfile scanning
2024-01-09 13:59:40,121 INFO o.a.j.r.ClassFinder: Will scan jar C:\temp\Performance Testing\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\lib\ext\jmeter-plugins-graphs-composite-2.0.jar with filter ExtendsClassFilter [parents=[interface org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.ResultRenderer], inner=false, contains=null, notContains=null]. Consider exposing JMeter plugins via META-INF/services, and add JMeter-Skip-Class-Scanning=true manifest attribute so JMeter can skip classfile scanning
2024-01-09 13:59:40,121 INFO o.a.j.r.ClassFinder: Will scan jar C:\temp\Performance Testing\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\lib\ext\jmeter-plugins-jmxmon-0.3.jar with filter ExtendsClassFilter [parents=[interface org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.ResultRenderer], inner=false, contains=null, notContains=null]. Consider exposing JMeter plugins via META-INF/services, and add JMeter-Skip-Class-Scanning=true manifest attribute so JMeter can skip classfile scanningc
```

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see any "error" here, these are information messages telling that some of [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) you have installed don't use [ServiceLoader](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/pull/5885)

So if there is an "error" it's close to the end of [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging). If the "error" is not there - try [increasing JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) to DEBUG level.